# Parsing time to string results in date

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel

I'm trying to parse an excel sheet where one of the columns is time viz. `5:15PM`, `7:10AM`. I can store these values successfully as strings just by doing `myTimeVar.toString()`.

However, when the time value has a `space` in between e.g. `5:15 PM` and `7:10 AM`, the `toString()` method returns a full blown date object as string. For instance, `myTimeVar.toString()` prints `Sat Dec 30 1899 16:15:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)` where `myTimeVar` is `5:15 PM` (with a space in between time and PM).

I even tried avoiding `toString()` and using `String()` but no success.

---

**Edit:** I'm using node and [convert-excel-to-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json) to do the parsing.

**Edit 2:** Node treats `5:15PM` (no space) as a string but `5:15 PM` (with space) as an object.

Comment: How are you parsing it? What is the context? Node.js?

Comment: @JaredSmith, yes I'm using node and https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json for parsing

Comment: If you are using the `toString()` method, it's obvious that the original data type is not string. So what's it?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Node is treating `5:15 PM` as an object because of the colon. But node treats `5:15PM` as string.

Comment: What kind of object? Try printing it

Comment: @CristianTraìna `1899-12-30T21:15:00.000Z`

Comment: @Hyperbola do `console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(theThingYouThinkIsADate))` and tell us what it prints, e.g. `[object Date]`, or `[object String]`, or whatever.

Comment: @JaredSmith It's `[object Date]`

Comment: Then it is a JavaScript Date object. It sounds though like your conversion library is improperly converting those values though, unless it's really supposed to be from the 1800's. I would guess it's a bug in that library, you might actually have more luck filing a github issue.